# How to make VMware player virtual machine to use eth0 IP address from host machine (Ubuntu 14.04) instead of VMnet?

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet, vmware

I am trying to configure an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine by using VMWare on another Ubuntu 14.04 machine as a host (looks unnecessary but I have to, the host system should not be a problem). I need the virtual machine to use the IP address that the host has as the exact one present in eth0, but whenever I try to use the NAT connection the virtual machine uses either the one present at the vmnet1 or vmnet8 interfaces, which I do not want to use.

So far, I have tried to edit the network configuration file by editing and having just the eth0 IP address but it still includes the other one (not sure if I am doing something wrong) or changing the IP addressed of the vm interfaces to the one that is present at the Ethernet interface (by using ifconfig vmnet1 X.X.X.X netmask Y.Y.Y.Y up), but to no avail. I have made the files editable by using chmod 777 on them, as well as the network configuration directory for vmware.
Is there anything I should do? Also, will there be any problem by having a duplicate IP address in the eth0 interfaces of the host and virtual machines?

Comment: What you are actually need to do is telling VMware to assign the ethernet card to your VM instead of the host, unless you need it on the host aswell. You then need to use a bridged connection while telling VMware which ethernet adapter to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the virtual interface of the guest a member of the "outside" network by selecting *bridged mode*. That way you can assign an IP-address that is valid there.

But you cannot assign the same IP-address that the host is using to the virtual interface. Two interfaces in the same network cannot have the same IP-address.